# how do I print the line which contains the word from preg_match?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

A field in mysql table "server_var_dump" which contains many details including USER_AGENT of the visitors of site. Now I only need USER_AGENTs containing line. Now I have written following script to match the USER_AGENT of the output string.
Now I need to print only those lines which contains the USER_AGENT

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT server_var_dump FROM pageviews LIMIT 0,10");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    //printf("%s", $row["server_var_dump"]);
    if(preg_match("/[USER_AGENT]/", $row["server_var_dump"])){
    echo "match found.";
    }
    else
    echo "No matches found";     
}
```

Please suggest me how do I print the line which contains USER_AGENT?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post sample input (i.e. a sample value from server_var_dump column)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with just printing the row once you got it?

```
$match_found = false;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    if(preg_match("/[USER_AGENT]/", $row["server_var_dump"])){
        echo $row["server_var_dump"];
        $match_found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if(!$match_found) {
    echo "No matches found";
}
```

Alternatively, you'll need to get the matched values like so:

```
$match_found = false;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $matches = array();
    if(preg_match("/[USER_AGENT](.+)/", $row["server_var_dump"], $matches)){
        echo $matches[1];
        $match_found = true;
    }
}
if(!$match_found) {
    echo "No matches found";
}
```

Comment: The row may contain A LOT of data, I think the OP just wants the line which contains the "[USER_AGENT]" string

Comment: I think the better approach would then be to match `/\n([^\n]*\[USER_AGENT\][^\n]*)/`

Answer (score 1):

```
if(preg_match("/.*\[USER_AGENT\].*/"   //don't forget escape [ and ] chars as Salaman A said
    , $row["server_var_dump"],$matches)){
    //. is every char except newline char, So,you should get all string
    echo "match found.";
    //use $matches[0]
}
else
    echo "No matches found";
```

Example:

```
preg_match('/.*a.*/',"bc\nbac\nxy",$m);
print($m[0]); //prints bac
```

Comment: `[` and `]` are special meta characters in patterns; consider escaping them.

Comment: @Salaman A: It's copied from question. I think it's an example because else it should be HTTP_USER_AGENT

Comment: Ummm... copying from question makes sense but may be not... the pattern `/.*[USER_AGENT].*/` will match the strings `U`, `S`, `E` and so on (`CIA AGENT` will match too :)

Comment: I assumed that OP will replace it by other string, edited now

Comment: @riad its not copied from question.. I have been working on it.. and yes its HTTP_USER_AGENT. I just made it short for easiness!

Answer (score 0):

ok part of o/p is something like this: http://pastebin.com/e1qHG64Q
when I give

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT server_var_dump FROM pageviews LIMIT 0,10");
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
$found = false;
$lines = explode("\n", $row["server_var_dump"]);
// $lines = explode("\\n", $row["server_var_dump"]);
for ($x = 0; $x < count($lines); $x++) {
    if(preg_match("/[HTTP_USER_AGENT]/", $row["server_var_dump"])==TRUE)
    //if (strstr($lines[$x], "[USER_AGENT]")==TRUE)
     {
        echo $lines[$x];
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

it gives me o/p like array array array array
and when the strstr is given as suggested it gives o/p like array ( array ( array (
. exploding the o/p with /n is probably not working.. any other kinda hack I can do to get just the USER_AGENT line from it?

Answer (score 0):

got the hack! ;)

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT server_var_dump FROM pageviews LIMIT 0,10");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
$found = false;
$data=str_replace("=>"," ",$row["server_var_dump"]);
$lines = explode("\n", $data);

// $lines = explode("\\n", $row["server_var_dump"]);
    str_replace("\n"," ",$row["server_var_dump"]);
for ($x = 0; $x < count($lines); $x++) {
    if(preg_match("[HTTP_WAP_CONNECTION]", $lines[$x])==TRUE){
    //if (strstr($lines[$x], "[USER_AGENT]")==TRUE)
     //{
            //if(strpos($lines[$x],"[HTTP_USER_AGENT]")){
                    //echo substr($lines[$x],18);
    $y=$x-1;
    echo "$lines[$y] \n";
    }
```